# explaining yaml, volumes flag, hyphens and sequences

Tags: yaml

In this segment of code:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./api
        target: /code
```

how come there is only one `-`?

Everywhere else I have seen a sequence, every time is listed with a hyphen except here.

Does this evaluate to comma separated values rather than individual array items?

Comment: Because is's a single item of `{ type: bind, source ./api, target: /code }` not three items.

Comment: from the perspective of the CLI if they were to be listed with - then they would evaluate to... type:bind source:./api target :/ code rather than type: bind,source: ./api,targer: /code ?

Comment: Maybe you should convert that into a format you're familiar with, e.g. JSON.

Comment: Don't have that option, gotta use it for a coding course